# Matlab: how to read correctly the months from a .txt file

Tags: matlab, textscan

I tried to read to .txt files in Matlab that include monthly information about solar radiation and temperatures. The months are as text i.e Jan, Feb, etc. Then with this information need to make some graphs to display the information per month, like for example monthly solar radiation having the months in the x-axis. Beyond that need to plot two graph on the same figure since I have Matlab 2015b need to use plotyy. 
THE PROBLEM: I thought that the months were correct read from the file, but when I plot takes all the months as January so I cannot plot correctly two graphs since the times are different.

The code that using is:

```
  fidata = fopen('Asmara-mon2.txt', 'r' );
   formatSpeci = '%s';
    N1 = 9;
%     h1=('Month' 'Temp'  'Tamin' 'Tadmin' 'Tadmax' 'Tamax' 'RH');
   h3 = textscan(fidata,formatSpeci,N1,'Delimiter','|');
    asmara_precipitation= textscan(fidata,'%{MM}D %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f');
%     formatIn = 'mm';
asmara_precipitation{1}=datenum(asmara_precipitation{1});
asmara_precipitation=cell2mat(asmara_precipitation); %% Month|  H_Gh|   SDm |SDd|SDastr |RR |RD |FF |DD
[MonthNum, MonthString] = month(asmara_precipitation(:,1));

p=find(average_day_radiation(:,1)<10);
q=find(diff(p)==1);
idx=[p average_day_radiation(p) average_day_radiation(p,2) average_day_radiation(p,4)];
consecutive_idx=[p(q) idx(q,2) idx(q,3) idx(q,4)];

% Graphic of bad radiation days

figure (44)

hold on

 plotyy(MonthNum,asmara_precipitation(:,7),consecutive_idx(:,1),consecutive_idx(:,2)) 
datetick('x','mmm')
```

Thank you in advance for any help and sorry to ask something that could seem silly.

Comment: I assume the first column, 'Month' is not in a supported date format. You should take a look on the online documentation of the month() function at https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/month.html#inputarg_F

Comment: Hey thanks I solved the issue already :) Should I post here or just delete my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep the last line, and add the following line above the `plot` command:

```
% The acquisition exact date: 2017-<MonthNum>-01 12:00:00
MonthNum=datenum(2017,MonthNum,1,12,0,0);
```

That will convert the MonthNum into a proper date, in which `datetick` will understand.